# how to launch Google Chrome with authenticated Proxies

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, proxy, puppeteer

I want to launch Google Chrome with authenticated proxies so I can connect a puppeteer instance with it. I'm using this cmd line to launch a new instance:

```
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

I managed to use authenticated proxies with Chrome, but it was a bit complicated, especially in my case, as I want to launch multiple Chrome browser, each with its own proxies.

I used this: [proxy-login-automator](https://github.com/Tahadaboussi/proxy-login-automator)

It worked fine, but as I said, it's bit complicated and it needs a bit of work, so I can integrate it as I want to use it. This is how am connecting to the Chrome instance:

```
const browserURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:9222';
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL});
const page = await browser.newPage();
```